# Unable to load the requested class: Pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

Everything is working when I use localhost database. But when I use the database in my domain. The PDF is not working anymore.

[image: PDF Error]

Comment: is that showing error when you auto load the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows, capitalization in paths does not create problem. But in Linux, it does.

When you autoload in linux server, use **`pdf`** not `Pdf`.

Comment: It is a class. So it has to be the same Cased name. You must name the class name and file name the same, and also same case.

Answer (score 6):

Class name all time in server start with Capital letter. When you create a file in library folder like "pdf.php" its work well in local server. But in live server, file name must be "Pdf.php". Please rename your file.

Comment: This one worked for me.